# how to clear stored results from r() only in stata 16.1

Tags: stata

I am not sure it is a bug, but I am unable to clear the results from the results stored r() with `return clear`.  `ereturn clear` works at clearing the stored results in e(). `results clear` also works but it clears all results.

Is there any way to clear only the stored results in r()?

The reason for that is that I am running the same program for different variables depending on some conditions. Clearing the results would make sure that the returned results are always "fresh" and not a results from the program that ran previously...

#### for reproduction

```
clear
sysuse auto

qui reg mpg rep78, r

* works
ereturn list
ereturn clear
ereturn list

* does not work
return list
return clear
return list // still there!

* workaround
qui reg mpg rep78, r
clear results 
return list
ereturn list
```

### edits

- using stata 16.1 on windows and linux. Same issue.

Comment: It's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the only way to clear the `r()` results is to declare an `rclass` program. This is both slightly unsatisfactory, and, I believe, the solution to your problem as you are concerned that the `r()` results your program produces will not be fresh.

Based on [this Statalist discussion](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1310137-return-clear) the following example demonstrates this behavior, and — if you wanted to be really generous — is actually a program that clears the `r()` results.

```
program rclassclear , rclass
    return local rclassclear
end

sysuse auto , clear
quietly summarize mpg

rclassclear

return list
```

Notice that the [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/preturn.pdf) points out a difference between `r()` and `return()` under “Storing results in r()”:

- `r()` are the returned results and
- `return()` are the results being assembled to that will be returned.

`return clear` clears `return()` not `r()`.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. Quite elegant albeit  "slightly unsatisfactory", but very very slightly :). Thank you for pointing out the distinction between r() and return(). I wasn't aware of that. Maybe this issue (of not clearing out the returned r()) is has to do with allowing for accessing r() values from a previous program within another program. In any case, your workaround does 'solve' this issue.

Comment: Thanks! To your point: "The reason for that is that I am running the same program for different variables depending on some conditions. Clearing the results would make sure that the returned results are always "fresh" and not a results from the program that ran previously." Running _any_ `rclass` program will clear `r()`, and then repopulate with any returned results.